# Linq query to get a duplicate key once along with multiple values out of a dictionary

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have the following dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, string> selectedDrivers = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 1, "Michael Schumacher" },
    { 2, "Michael Schumacher" },
    { 3, "Jensen Button" }
};
```

What I try to achieve is a linq query that will find the duplicates, retrieve the name only once, along with the positions this duplicate has. So, for example, the above would result in `"Michael Schumacher" 1 2`. I would like the result to go into a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`.

Getting excited fast, this little nugget I wrote seems to be going in the right direction, except that I have Michael Schumacher twice. And it's not yet in a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`

```
var a = selectedDrivers.GroupBy(a => a.Value).
        Where(b => b.Count() > 1);
```

Comment: You can't do that in only one Linq request I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = selectedDrivers.GroupBy(a=>a.Value)
            .Where(g=>g.Count() > 1)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(a=>a.Key).ToList());
```